# Using an xml file retrieved from firebase as database, when saved in internal storage doesnt give permissions

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-internal-storage

So im kinda new in this Android thing, we are trying to have data in an xml file that is being stored in internal storage, now, the thing is that we have tried to retrieve data from other files created directly from string and is read with no problem, but when we get the file from firebase, it says that the file coulnt be found, yet, we can see it in the device file explorer just like the other files that we created. We think that i might has to do with file permissions or something, we are not sure.
i´d like to know if there is a way of changeing this permissions if it is the problem or what would you suggest to solve this problm?

This is the creation of the file without issue:

```html
public void crearXML() throws FileNotFoundException {//Esto se podra borar despues
        String res="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" +
                "<base_palabras>" +
                "<palabra><id>papa</id><contenido>African darter</contenido></palabra><palabra><id>comida</id><contenido>Thomson's gazelle</contenido></palabra><palabra><id>Hombre</id><contenido>Eastern cottontail rabbit</contenido></palabra><palabra><id>omfg</id><contenido>Smith's bush squirrel</contenido></palabra><palabra><id>Over</id><contenido>Crab, red lava</contenido></palabra><palabra><id>Larvae</id><contenido>Moose</contenido></palabra><palabra><id>Freud</id><contenido>Steller's sea lion</contenido></palabra><palabra><id>Coral</id><contenido>Northern fur seal</contenido></palabra><palabra><id>RainbowShrimp</id><contenido>Otter, cape clawless</contenido></palabra><palabra><id>Octopus</id><contenido>Blue-faced booby</contenido></palabra></base_palabras>";
        FileOutputStream FOS= openFileOutput("basePalabras.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        try {
            FOS.write(res.getBytes(),0,res.length());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            FOS.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now this is the creation of the file that get from firebase:

```html
StorageReference referencia = mStorageRef.child("base_palabras2.xml");
        try {
            final FileOutputStream FOS=new FileOutputStream( new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "base_palabras2.xml"));
            final File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "base_palabras2.xml");
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            referencia.getFile(file)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Archivo descargado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Archivo no descargado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Fallo en recuperar el XML",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        try {
            crearXML();//Esto es para la prueba mientras aparece los archivos descargados
            leerXml();
            testTree.print();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

[So, here is how the files look with their respective permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIZzA.jpg)

Comment: Who stored that xml file in internal storage? If your app did it then your complaint does not make sense as if when an app can write to s file it can certainly read.

Comment: It was uploaded manually directly on firebase.

Comment: Files on firebase are not considered files in internal storage. So i ask again: how did that file from firebase land in internal storage?

Comment: With th storge reffrence, i think it fills a File class, in this case the one that was created to create a file in internal storage. so this storagereference supposedly returns bytes to create the file.

Comment: Firebase has its own File class not to be confused with the normal File class.

Comment: I see now that you download a file from firebase to internal storage getFilesDir(). You should be able to read that file there too. If you are complaining that you cannot read the file then i see no code that tries to read the file. `but when we get the file from firebase, it says that the file coulnt be found` WHen does this happen exactly? Where is the code that produces that message?

Comment: At the moment we start to read the xml file with FileInputStream like : FileInputStream fis=getApplicationContext().openFileInput("base_palabras2.xmll");

Comment: it says "open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)", and yet we see it in the file explorer in that directory, and as i said before, with tho other file in the directory it has no problem. Also when we open the file in the IDE it is there as it should be

Comment: `"base_palabras2.xmll"` Is that a typo? xmll?

Comment: yeah, my bad it is "xml"